# How do I change lightswitch publish location?

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

Basically I've deployed a Lightswitch desktop application on web server (i.e. www.firstsite.com), now I must move the application to another server with another address (i.e. www.secondsite.com).

How do I can change the publish location making the installed clients to automatically detect the address change?

Answer (score 0):

Just *publish* the application again (to a different folder than the first time), & enter the new site's information in the *Publish Wizard*.

Comment: This solve first question part but second: " publish location making the installed clients to automatically detect the address change"

Comment: If the application was installed via Click-Once, you'll have to uninstall it, then reinstall it from the new location. If it's a web application, there's no way to "automatically have the installed clients detect the address change". They just have to start using the new URL.

Comment: Are you sure that don't exists a kind of 301 or [302 redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302)? Have you tested it?